# Inserir um id apartir de outro, codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá, boa tarde!!
preciso de ajuda em um seguinte caso sobre codeigniter, tenho minha tabela de Clientes e minha tabela de Chamados, no cadastro de um chamado, preciso referencia-lo a um cliente, o "registro de chamado" é na View do cliente, como faço pra pegar o id desse cliente e inserir na tabela chamados ? tenho uma coluna chamada chamado_id_cliente, que serve para fazer esse "join", alguem pode me ajudar?

no momento meu insert está assim

```
function novoChamado(){
  $data = array(
    'chamado_atividade'          => $this->input->post('chamado_atividade'),
    'chamado_duracao_minuto'     => $this->input->post('chamado_duracao_minuto'),
    'chamado_duracao_hora'       => $this->input->post('chamado_duracao_hora'),
    'chamado_assunto'            => $this->input->post('chamado_assunto'),
    'chamado_data'               => $this->input->post('chamado_data'),
    'chamado_hora'               => $this->input->post('chamado_hora'),
    'chamado_atendente_rf'       => $this->input->post('chamado_atendente_rf'),
    'chamado_atendente_cliente'  => $this->input->post('chamado_atendente_cliente'),
    'chamado_obs'                => $this->input->post('chamado_obs'),
    'chamado_telefone'           => $this->input->post('chamado_telefone'),
    'chamado_email'              => $this->input->post('chamado_email'),
    'chamado_id_cliente'         => ??????
```

minha função de listar chamados está assim

```
public function listarChamadosCliente($cliente_id){

  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('chamado');
  $this->db->join('cliente', 'cliente.cliente_id = chamado.chamado_id_cliente');
  $this->db->where('chamado.chamado_id_cliente ='.$cliente_id );
  $this->db->order_by('chamado_data');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  if($query->num_rows() < 1){
    return FALSE;
  }
  return $query->result();
}
```

Agradeço desde Já!!!

Comment: Quando você carrega a view do cliente você não guarda um identificador, na url, campo oculto, sessão (apesa dessa ultima eu não gostar) ou alguma outra forma?

Comment: Guardo sim na url, fica então, exemplo com o id de nº 10 http://localhost/RFCRM/C_Cliente/exibir/10

Comment: Então no entendi sua pergunta, você tá passando o identificador mas não consegue pegar ele no controller?

Comment: "localhost/RFCRM/C_Cliente/novoChamado/10" recebendo como parametro o identificador já resolveria.
Ou adicionar esse id como um campo oculto no form (não é o ideal mas funciona) também resolveria

Comment: então ficaria assim? function novoChamado($cliente_id){
  $data = array(
   [...]
    'chamado_id_cliente'         => $cliente_id

Comment: Dessa forma acredito que já resolva seu problema

Comment: E se serve como dica dá uma olhada nesse cara https://github.com/fadakar/codeigniter_viewModel_binder Ajuda a fazer o bind dos valores do form para o objeto de forma mais simples.

Comment: deu isso 
 Too few arguments to function M_chamado::novoChamado(), 0 passed in htdocs\RFCRM\application\controllers\C_chamado.php on line 20 and exactly 1 expected